# Cursor size (number of results)

Tags: postgresql

How I can know cursor size (numbers of results)?

```
c CURSOR IS SELECT foo FROM mytable WHERE name='ok';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, a cursor is NOT the result. You can use a cursor to GET your results row by row, and at the end of this row by row operations, you know how many results you got.

To know how many records you will (possibly) get, you can use a

```
select count(*) from ... where ...
```

assuming you have an index on column name, you could also write:

```
select count(name) from foo where name = 'ok'
```

Comment: Yes, but I also want know the number of results

Comment: Though, you can count them as you fetch the rows.

Comment: I don't want use count function, sorry.

Comment: is there any property in cursor object to know the result size?

Comment: NO, this is not possible by design.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to obtain the total number of results without issuing a separate count query, you can:

```
SELECT count(1) OVER (), ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

The count will be unaffected by ORDER/LIMIT clauses.